# Get error msg from ResponseStatusException with ResponseErrorHandler

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I have an API which throws ResponseStatusException  in case of error :

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND, "My error msg");
```

In the client side I have :

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = this.builder.errorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler()).build();
// Then I use restTemplate to call URLs with restTemplate.exchange(...)
```

And the ResponseErrorHandler :

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {
 @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {

        return (httpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR || httpResponse.getStatusCode()
            .series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {

        String error = new String(httpResponse.getBody().readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    }
}
```

Problem is the getBody() is empty, and when I inspect the httpResponse I cannot find the "My error msg", it seems that it's not present in the object.
Is there any way to get the msg?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the RestTemplate instance using the RestTemplateBuilder like this:

```
public class xyz {

RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public xyz(RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder) {
        restTemplate = restTemplateBuilder
          .errorHandler(new RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler())
          .build();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please elaborate a bit on the how and why your solution works.

Answer (score -1):

Catch HttpClientErrorException as follows:

```
try{
            HttpEntity<ProfileDto> entity = new HttpEntity<ProfileDto>(profileDto,headers);
            response= restTemplate.postForEntity(environment.getProperty("app.filedownload.url"),entity, xxxxxx.class);
        }catch(HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException  e ){
            if(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.equals(e.getStatusCode())){
            //do your stufs
            }
        }catch(Exception  e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thx but I would like to use the ResponseErrorHandler